# SML - read file and convert to datatype

Tags: file, sml

I defined datatype

```
datatype DT = D1 of string 
    | D2 of string 
    | D3 of string 
    | D4 of string*string
```

In a file there are some data like

```
D1("str1")
D4("str2","str3")
...
```

I need a list with data from this file. But when I read the file, the type list is string... how can I make this list type "DT type"?

```
Data.txt
D1("str1")
D4("str2","str3")
D2("str4")



datatype DT = D1 of string 
    | D2 of string 
    | D3 of string 
    | D4 of string*string

val infile = "Data.txt" ;
fun readlist (infile : string) =
    let 
      val ins = TextIO.openIn infile 
      fun loop ins = 
          case TextIO.inputLine ins of 
            SOME line => line :: loop ins 
          | NONE      => [] 
    in 
      loop ins before TextIO.closeIn ins 
    end;
```

Comment: Can you post some code?

Comment: You need to write a parser that can take strings of the requisite format and return `DT` values. Is there any restriction on the strings? If not, a line like `D4(",",",",")` appearing in `Data.txt` would be ambiguous. You would need some sort of convention for escaping quote marks that would render such a line ill-formed. On the other hand -- if e.g. there are never any commas in the middle of the strings then parsing would be somewhat trivial.

Comment: @John Coleman thank you. I'd like to do it automatically, while reading the file. But it seems impossible....

Comment: Presumably SML code (or some other programming language) will be creating these files. Why not tweak the format so that e.g. the Value `D4("a","b")` is stored as the tab-delimited line containing  the 3 fields `D4`, `a`, `b` separated by tabs? Or perhaps store `D4`, `a` and `b` on 3 successive lines. As long as there is some safe delimiter (e.g. tabs, commas, or newlines) that will never appear inside of the strings, such a format is both easy to write and easy to parse.